# Calculus III question

Tags: vectors, systems-of-equations

This question has been boggling me for over $30$ mins and I'm feeling really stupid because I know that this thing is super easy to solve:

Let $u=8i+2j$, $v=i+j$ and $w=i-j$. Find scalars $a$ and $b$ such that $u=av+bw$.

Comment: What attempts have you made on the question?

Comment: I tried to switch u=8i+2j into i=u/8-1/4j but I keep getting stuck

Answer (score 1):

$$8i+2j=a(i+j)+b(i-j)$$

You have two equations to solve. One in $i$ and one in $j$.

$$8=a+b$$

$$2=a-b$$

I'm sure you can solve it from here.

Comment: How can you separate them into two? I had already organized it the way you did such that 8i+2j=a(i+j)+b(i-j) but I don't understand how you got to separate that into 8=a+b and 2=a-b

Comment: For the two vectors to be equal, the $i$ and $j$ components must be equal.

Comment: FOIL the RHS ...

Comment: So you omitted the directional i and j? So it should be 8i=ai+bi and 2j=aj-bj correct?

Comment: Yes, that is the case. So $a=5$ and $b=3$

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $$i=\frac{1}{2}\left(v+w\right)$$
and $$j=\frac{1}{2}(v-w)$$

Comment: I don't understand how you got there

Comment: To isolate $i$ we want to cancel the $j$'s. Since the coefficient of $j$ is $1$ in $v$ and $-1$ in $w$, we simply add $v+w$. Then we divide by $2$ to get a $1$ as the final coefficient of $i$. Similar logic for isolating $j$.